# Viability of stacking passengers in an airplane cabin

Tags: air-travel, aircraft, seating

I've came across on youtube a new design for [stacking passengers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5gCUMdtj3c) in an airplane cabin, that looks at first sight interesting.

[image: screen capture from video]

*What would be the advantages and drawbacks of such a design?* Why this is not common in today's airplanes?

*Note: I cross-posted this question on aviation stack exchange too, as I wanted to get both technical / social feedback.*

Comment: [Related](/questions/21713/why-are-there-no-2-3-4-5-tier-bunk-beds-on-airplanes)

Comment: I think this probably makes a great question on Aviation Stack Exchange, but I'm not so sure about the fit here.  I think any discussion of the advantages and drawbacks of the design is heavily dependent on the technical feasibility, which this community doesn't have the knowledge to answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a completely hypothetical question seeking opinions about seating layout design.

Comment: @pnuts why do you think it is spam? A question that requires you to go follow a link to understand what is being asked is not a good question. Once the picture is included you can answer without following the link. If you think the asker is promoting the scheme, the presence or absence of a picture is unlikely to make a difference.

Comment: @pnuts I know that if you are paranoid doesn't mean that they are not after you but c'mon. :)

Comment: @pnuts I wasn't referring to spam comment.

Comment: @pnuts Item d..

Comment: Advantages and drawbacks is a discussion. It's not a "one right answer" question. Great question for a regular forum but not for Stack Exchange which is not a regular forum.

Comment: @Calchas; It's not off topic. Passenger planes are on topic. It's a bad question, but not because of its topic.

Comment: @pnuts: That's just nuts. Calling every aspect of questions "topic" makes no sense at all. What term on SE is used in the case you actually want to refer to Classic meaning of "topic"? Absolutely nuts.

Comment: I started a met topic about this. Erm a meta question? A meta thread? I'm not sure if it's on-topic but it's about a topic within Stack Exchange's scope: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283559/

Comment: @pnuts Yes, I'm affiliated to the patent holder, it's my brother. And no it's not for promotion, I was arguing with him about the practicality of this scheme (notably here about the livability of the thing) and wanted some neutral opinions about it.

Comment: As for the off-topicness, I first posted on **aviation.se** and was being told _"The question doesn't seem to be on-topic here, it relates more to the travel.se scope."_ -- I'm a long time user of SO and all this nitpicking about being on/off topic is a bit boring.

Comment: @pnuts: I might ask about it on EL&U or Quora at some point. I started thinking maybe it's a common English misnomer but then [started to find the old MSE questions about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192086/) and it seems it is SE-specific jargon. It's translated literally on the non-English sites too. I don't know if it's any less confusing on those. I initially thought off-topic and out-of-scope had exactly the same meaning but the latter allows for us to elsewhere detail what the scope is. The "topic" is just "travel".

Comment: This is on [aviation.se] here: [Viability of stacking passengers in an airplane cabin](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/30791/753) (and actually somewhat well received, net +8 votes and five answers so far)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44196/discussion-on-question-by-laurent-gregoire-viability-of-stacking-passengers-in-a).

Answer (score 2):

I speak only as a frequent flyer who once worked for an airline, not an aircraft designer.

The main point of contention with such a design will the be the trade-off between the extra passenger capacity and apparently significantly *weight* of those structures.

As as Business Class passenger, I would find those compartments quite confining.  The current prevailing herring-bone layout is cramped enough.

Comment: Downvote because?  I'd rather correct any issues, totally unwarranted.

Comment: You don't participate in the voting system. Why do you care about other people's votes when you don't vote yourself?